# Calabash Automation Testing

Tags: testing, automation, appium, calabash

I am new in Automating the apps for testing Android and i like to advance to this level... I have researched for Appium and Calabash... but knowing the difference pretty complicated.. There are my questions:

1: For Calabash, do we need the source code, i mean can i have APK and give test cases and so on? or do I NEED the source code even if im using the elements from app?

2: I heard i can use the Appium with cucumber, and same question do i need source code for that?

I have researched about it and all i get is for Apple apps... but nothing much for android...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need source code. All you need is apk file, packageName and ActivityName to launch the app.

Comment: Is that for Calabash or Appium?

Answer (score 0):

In Appium framework, all you need is app file (for android it will be simply .apk file).

Source code will be never needed, all elements from UI that you would like to interact with, can be simply get from Appium Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

For both calabash and Appium you don't need to source code. you can automate application using apk file.

Yes you can use Appium with cucumber.

To find object locators of application use calabash console and Android UI Viewer, Appium GUI.